# Arangodb connection fail on docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Tags: docker, docker-compose, arangodb, arangojs

I'm trying to initialize my docker arangodb, but keep getting connection error: I've tried changing the server endpoint to http+tcp://..... but the error remains, what could be happening?

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    container_name: arangodb
    build: .
    environment:
      - ARANGO_DB_NAME="mydba"
      - ARANGO_DB_USER="user"
      - ARANGO_DB_PASSWORD="123"
    ports:
      - '2010:8529'
    expose:
      - '2010'
    volumes:
      - ./arango-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM arangodb
## Environment variables
ENV ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
```

arango-dump/01-Create.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/arangosh \
--server.endpoint=unix:///tmp/arangodb-tmp.sock \
--server.password ${ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD} \
--javascript.execute-string "db._createDatabase(${ARANGO_DB_NAME}, [{username: ${ARANGO_DB_USER}, password: ${ARANGO_DB_PASSWORD}}]);"
```

Error:

```
arangodb | /entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-Create.sh
arangodb | 2020-03-25T03:49:52Z [255] ERROR [979b9] JavaScript exception in file '/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/arango-database.js' at 1017,40: ArangoError 2001: not connected\n!  var requestResult = this._connection.POST('/_api/database', data);\n!                                       ^\nstacktrace: ArangoError: not connected\n    at Proxy.ArangoDatabase._createDatabase (/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/arango-database.js:1017:40)\n    at (command-line):1:4\n
arangodb exited with code 1
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use port `8999` for your server endpoint

```
--server.endpoint=tcp://127.0.0.1:8999
```

This works for me on 3.6.2.

In your case there is no need for a `Dockerfile`, nor `expose` in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I decided to use another database system but ill try out your solution on a later project :)